# The NetBeans IDE issues unusual compiler errors on "Clean and Build" or external changes.The IDE becomes unaware of the JPA generated static metamodel

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, java-ee-7, netbeans-8

I'm completely tired of using the NetBeans IDE 8.x (currently using 8.0.1) for months - it just looks like a hell (seriously). When some external changes are made to the project (especially a Java EE web application - containing hundredth of Java classes in different packages) or an attempt is made to *Clean and Build* to project (especially to the enterprise module), *Background Scanning of Projects* is initiated which unusually propagates compile-time errors in almost all classes in which classes from the JPA generated [static metamodel](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria002.htm) are used in the EJB module as can be seen in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uilLZ.png).

[image]

Surprisingly, these erroneous classes, if opened in the IDE, no compile-time errors (indicated by a red curly line) are shown anymore by the IDE - I cannot say the reason because I myself do not know.

Sometimes, if the IDE is restarted, it initiates *Background Scanning of Projects* that may remove these errors (in most cases it does not), if the IDE it restarted again and again for at least 10 times!

When and why this happens is quite uncertain but there one certain thing - it happens because of *the JPA generated static metamodel*. The IDE apparently becomes unaware of the classes that end with an underscore (the classes of the metamodel). This is merely a wastage of time - it takes hours or days to build an application - I had to create all of these classes all over again from scratch one by one several times.

---

This did not happen prior to the version 8.x. Both 8.0 and 8.0.1 have the same issue (I'm not even quite sure about whether it is an issue or not. While using NetBeans 8.0, I incorrectly assumed that the later release would not impose this behaviour).

---

To reproduce this problem,

- The application must have a JPA generated static metamodel.
- The application should (not must) be using a *Class Library* that holds interfaces for remote EJBs.

In very small applications, this may or may not happen (I myself cannot confirm about the cause of this problem quite well and cannot say anything about this).

---

Does someone encounter this kind of problems while using NetBeans IDE especially 8.x - this makes almost impossible to develop an application using this IDE - it is merely a frustration? Does the IDE have some settings that I might be missing? Might I be deploying the application in a wrong way?

I can say only one thing - The *Background Scanning of Project* is performed incorrectly by the IDE or it is just a hell.

The way I deploy the application (Java EE containing some remote EJBs (including many local EJBs) which are held by a *Class Library*)

- Clean and Build the Class Library
- Clean and Build the Enterprise application (the EJB module denoted by a triangle by the IDE) (this step is the culprit)
- Clean and build the Class Library again (after completion of the above two steps)
- Deploy the application

These steps are performed at the very first time the application is built or some major changes are made to the application. Otherwise, only the last two steps are sufficient to deploy the application to the server (and I do it usually).

With this problem, it is almost impossible to proceed. Is there any (at least temporary) solution/workaround to this?

<sub>One additional thing. This not only happens in Java EE applications but I have another project that uses Spring in which this problem often happens.</sub>

---

**EDIT :**

Sometimes (again uncertain when this may happen), major options including *Clean and Build* of the submenu of a Class Library are disabled preventing us from doing *Clean and Build* as indicated by the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ILx.png) (right click on the Class Library to open the submenu).

[image]

Which is enabled, when the IDE is restarted for random number of times (1 time, 2 times, 5 times, 10 times or even more. It is completely uncertain how many times restarting the IDE can make those options of the submenu enable).

---

**EDIT 2 :**

The application uses the following major components.

- JSF 2.2.8-02
- PrimeFaces 5.1 (Community Release)
- PrimeFaces Extension 2.1.0 (Community Release)
- OmniFaces 1.8.1
- EclipseLink 2.5.2 having JPA 2.1 (along with EclipseLink JPA ModelGen)
- Java EE 7
- GlassFish Server 4.1
- NetBeans IDE 8.0.1
- JDK 8u25

Comment: You provide lots of information and complaints but very little in terms of an actual question.

Comment: If you have a Short, Self Contained Compilable Example, please do post it somewhere.

Comment: Does your problem cause Clean and Build to issue compile errors in the Output window ?  Is your issue only limited to incorrect Red Squiggle annotations?

Comment: @Ryan : There is no SSCCE I can think of. Apparently, this happens when the application exceeds some size (with a JPA static metamodel and a class library) and when this happens, it prevents from deploying/running the application. Therefore, there are compiler-errors internally. If the application is forcibly deployed, a run-time exception occurs indicating, *cannot find symbol* (the symbol is from JPA static metamodel classes)

Comment: At this stage, I can only say, there is no fair logical way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

When you see incorrect error indicators on classes in the Projects tab, try this: from the menu select Source -> Scan for External Changes.

Comment: When those errors occur, I try doing this too but it makes no difference at all (very sadly). JPA static metamodel classes loook safe on the compile-time classpath but the IDE is (apparently) unaware of them.

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug to the NetBeans team: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: Good. Please add a link to the bugzilla issue, so everyone can follow the progress of resolution.