# NetBeans issues a low memory message quite frequently

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, netbeans, java-ee-7, netbeans-8

While developing Java EE applications, the NetBeans IDE (currently using 8.0.2 but the issue is not restricted/limited to this version only) issues a low memory message quite frequently.

For example, while modifying and saving some Java classes (especially, JPA entity classes), the memory soon gets over-flooded after repeating this *modifying and saving* process for merely 10 to 15 entity classes. The IDE issues a [low memory message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pel6S.png) disturbing the whole system severely.

[image]

It leaves only one alternative which is to restart the system and I indeed have been wasting more time in restarting the system than actually developing Java EE applications for couple of years :). I have not yet seen anything about this issue over the internet.

The auto-deploy (Deploy on save) option on the IDE is turned off forever. I never use this facility as it causes the heap/PermGen space to get over-flooded quite soon.

This may or may not happen in small toy applications. I am only talking about Java EE applications using a Java EE compliant application server.

I see if there is no way to get around this problem, then this IDE cannot be used in developing real Java EE applications because dealing with this problem basically takes more time than the actual development time and otherwise, the solution may be to lean towards other IDEs like Eclipse, IntelliJ Idea, JDeveloper etc, if they go better.

I am currently using,

- GlassFish Server 4.1/Java EE 7
- JDK 8u45
- NetBeans 8.0.2

Is there a solution somewhere in the world?

<sub>NetBeans tends to be slower than other IDEs on Windows but this is far beyond the single term *slow*.</sub>

---

The picture is taken from a simple test web application (thus not an enterprise application). In enterprise applications, changing a single character in a single entity class is not affordable. One is likely to run into a [big problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26535853), if attempted. Fixing those errors shown in the link may take hours or probably the whole day or so.

Not to mention again that I am not talking anything other than large scale applications involving Java EE or other platforms like Spring.

Long story short : Nothing can prevent me from wondering as to how it is affordable to use this IDE in software industries. It is no longer usable in this way (Nothing to abuse. Honestly, I kept patience for almost three years. I am merely wasting time using this IDE).

Comment: whats your machine configuration ?

Comment: I am still using 32-bit Windows XP (SP 3), Intel Core I3 and 6 GB of RAM. On 32-bit systems, only around 2.5 to 3 GB of RAM is in use but this much amount of memory should be quite sufficient. Allocating more memory to Heap/ParmGen merely delays the memory overflow problem but it does not solve the problem itself. The problem occurs for sure early or late even when allocating them a large amount of memory.